# Copying files to specific folder declared in a CSV file using Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, csv, copy-item

i am quite new to powershell and i am trying to make a script that copy files to certain folders that are declared in a CSV file. But till now i am getting errors from everywhere and can't find nothing to resolve this issue.

I have this folders and .txt files created in the same folder as the script.

**Till now i could only do this:**

```
$files = Import-Csv .\files.csv 
$files
 foreach ($file in $files) {
    $name = $file.name
    $final = $file.destination
    Copy-Item $name -Destination $final   
  }
```

**This is my CSV**

```
name;destination
file1.txt;folderX
file2.txt;folderY
file3.txt;folderZ
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include the errors that you are experiencing

Comment: Specify the delimiter character your csv file uses `;`, since this is different to the default **comma**. Also, your csv is lacking headers so add those to the cmdlet aswell. Try `$files = Import-Csv .\files.csv -Delimiter ';' -Header 'name' ,'destination'`

Comment: Does your csv actually have the headings "name" and "destination"?

Comment: Thank you theo! i just needed the -Delimiter ";"

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments indicate, if you are not using default system delimiters, you should make sure to specify them.

I also recommend typically to use quotes for your csv to ensure no problems with accidentally including an entry that includes the delimiter in the name.

```bsh
@"
"taco1.txt";"C:\temp\taco2;.txt"
"@ | ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter ';' -Header @('file','destination')
```

will output

```
file      destination
----      -----------
taco1.txt C:\temp\taco2;.txt
```

The quotes make sure the values are correctly interpreted. And yes... you can name a file `foobar;test..txt`. Never underestimate what users might do.

If you take the command `Get-ChildItem | Select-Object BaseName,Directory | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation` and review the output, you should see it quoted like this.

### Sourcing Your File List

One last tip. Most of the time I've come across a CSV for file input lists a CSV hasn't been needed. Consider looking at grabbing the files you in your script itself.

For example, if you have a folder and need to filter the list down, you can do this on the fly very easily in PowerShell by using [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).

For example:

```bsh
$Directory = 'C:\temp'
$Destination = $ENV:TEMP
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
```

If you need to have more granular matching control, consider using the `Where-Object` cmdlet and doing something like this:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Where-Object Name -match '(taco)|(burrito)' | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
```

Often you'll find that you can easily use this type of filtering to keep CSV and input files out of the solution.

### example

Using techniques like this, you might be able to get files from 2 directories, filter the match, and copy all in a short statement like this:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' -Filter '*.xlsx' -Recurse | Where-Object Name -match 'taco' | Copy-Item -Destination $ENV:TEMP -Verbose
```

Hope that gives you some other ideas! Welcome to Stack Overflow.